# Converting EDT/EST to UTC

Tags: java, jodatime

The code below seems to convert to BST instead. Am I doing something silly?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    @Test
    public void testTimeInterval(){
        String DAY_SHIFT="08:00-17:15";
        System.out.println(toInterval(DAY_SHIFT, "America/New_York", "UTC"));
    }

    public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm";
    public static List<LocalTime> toInterval(String str, String sourceTZ, String destTZ) {
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(str)){
            final DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(TIME_FORMAT).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID(sourceTZ));
            String[] tokens = str.split("-");
            if (tokens!=null && tokens.length==2){
                try{
                    long start = timeFormat.parseMillis(tokens[0]);
                    long end = timeFormat.parseMillis(tokens[1]);
                    DateTime startTime = new DateTime(start, DateTimeZone.forID(sourceTZ)).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(destTZ));
                    DateTime endTime = new DateTime(end, DateTimeZone.forID(sourceTZ)).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID(destTZ));
                    return Arrays.asList(new LocalTime(startTime, DateTimeZone.forID(destTZ)),
                            new LocalTime(endTime, DateTimeZone.forID(destTZ)));
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code prints `[13:00:00.000, 22:15:00.000]`. According to [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20130606T08&p1=179&p2=136) link, it's an hour off should be `[12:00:00.000, 21:15:00.000]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've *only* provided a time of day. What day are you interested in? That will affect the mapping to UTC. If you mean *today*, you should specify that explicitly. It looks like you really want to parse to a `LocalTime`, then construct an appropriate `LocalDateTime` by joining that with some appropriate `LocalDate` (which will depend on what you're trying to achieve).

My guess is that it's actually doing it for January 1st 1970 - at which point the UTC offset of New York was -5, not -4. You can verify that by logging `startTime` and `endTime` in full.

Also for simplicity, I'd strongly recommend calling `DateTimeZone.forId` just twice, at the start of the method instead of *every* time you need a zone.

You should also consider what you want to happen if the local date/time is ambiguous, or potentially skipped due to DST transitions. If you pick a date which doesn't include any transitions, this will never happen of course.